# What is the best way to invalidate a cached value of Mono?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, netty, reactor

I'll try to explain my use case as easy as possible. Before I call an external web service in my application I'm requesting an oauth access token from a token provider using the Spring Webflux WebClient and I'm caching the value so it's reused for the next time I need it. Whenever a request fails with error code 401 I want to invalidate the cache and retry with a new token.

Everything works fine accept that I'm not sure about the cache invalidation of the Mono.

Is it a good idea to store in a boolean variable if the cache needs to be invalidated? On retry when subscribing to the auth Mono the invalidating cache predicate will be true which will invalidate the cache and a new request will be done.

Any other ideas?

Sample code:

```
@Component
public class AccessTokenService {

    private final WebClient accessTokenClient;
    private final Mono<Token> accessTokenMono;
    private final AtomicBoolean cacheInvalidated = new AtomicBoolean();

    public AccessTokenService() {
        accessTokenClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("example-token-uri")
                .build();

        accessTokenMono = initAccessTokenMono();
    }

    private Mono<Token> initAccessTokenMono() {
        return accessTokenClient.post()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        // Some credentials as parameters
                        .build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Token.class)
                // Always set cache invalidated to false when we get the response
                .doOnSuccess(token -> cacheInvalidated.set(false))
                .cacheInvalidateIf(accessToken -> cacheInvalidated.get());
    }

    public Mono<Token> getAccessTokenMono() {
        // Shared for all requests
        return accessTokenMono;
    }

// Called on 401
    public void setCacheInvalidated() {
        // Sets the predicate to true. For the next subscription the cache will be invalidated and a new request to the token provider will occur
        cacheInvalidated.set(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: See other `Mono.cache()` variants. Or `cacheInvalidateIf()`, or `cacheInvalidateWhen()`...

Comment: @artem-bilan I'm using `cacheInvalidateIf()` in my example. The different variations of `Mono.cache()` provide the ability of TTL, but I don't want to use this approach as the token have a dynamic expiration time and it might not get invalidated although it's invalid. I think with `cacheInvalidateWhen()` I can go as far as with `cacheInvalidateIf()`. Do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: All of them are called only when subscription happens to that `Mono`. So, one subscriber may use a cached value, but other will invalidate it and re-fetch. Not sure what else you'd like to have.

Comment: Yeah... Sorry, I really missed that `cacheInvalidateIf()` in the end. So, no: all good so far. I had doubts about your `doOnSuccess()`, but now I agree with you. All good so far, with me. You may ignore my comments since I didn't give you any other opinion :-)

Comment: @artem-bilan no prob, all fine! Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for your problem? @nailer_boxer

Comment: @Archmede I used the provided sample code. Another approach that I had in mind was that the cached object contains the information if it's needs to be invalidated (in this case the Token class has a field `valid` or something like that) and `cacheInvalidateIf` reads it. However I found the solution in the description a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attempting to keep the state of a dirty flag in sync with the validity of the `Mono`, why not simply swap in a new `Mono` when you detect a 401? I'm also having it refresh the token periodically via `cache()`, but that's not explicitly required for what you're trying to do.

```
@Component
public class AccessTokenService {
    private static final Duration TOKEN_REFRESH_INTERVAL = Duration.ofHours(1);
    private final WebClient accessTokenClient;
    private final AtomicReference<Mono<Token>> accessTokenMono = new AtomicReference<>();

    public AccessTokenService() {
        accessTokenClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("example-token-uri")
            .build();

        accessTokenMono.set(initAccessTokenMono());
    }

    private Mono<Token> initAccessTokenMono() {
        return accessTokenClient.post()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                // Some credentials as parameters
                .build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Token.class)
            .cache(token -> TOKEN_REFRESH_INTERVAL,         // refresh every interval
                exc -> Duration.ZERO, () -> Duration.ZERO); // don't cache exceptions or empties
    }

    public Mono<Token> getAccessTokenMono() {
        // Shared for all requests
        return accessTokenMono.get();
    }

    // Called on 401
    public void setCacheInvalidated() {
        // Plug in a new Mono so subsequent requests get a new token
        accessTokenMono.set(initAccessTokenMono());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I like the idea. Very elegant solution!
In my case I don't need the TTL, as I would like to use the cached value as long as possible, but that's not important.
Thanks :)